# Navigation Drawer with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I would like to ask for advice, I am trying to implement a Navigation Drawer with `Fragments`, but is not clear for me, how can I replace the `Fragments` depending on the selection of the drawer, more specifically, do I need to create a `Fragment` for each option and then use a switch? Or is there another way to do it, I've seen a couple of videos some of them seems to be using just one `Fragment`, but is not clear for me how can the content be replaced without creating another `Fragment` class, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/) library by MikePenz.

This is how I replace fragments: https://github.com/lalongooo/permutas-sep/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/permutassep/ui/ActivityMain.java#L133

Comment: so that means he is creating a fragment class per selection, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on a case.

I think the most major example of `Fragment` is [Google's official one](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). It uses a common `Fragment` class. However class is the same, each instances are apart. And it demonstrates to pass different arguments with `Bundle` objects for each instances.

I think it is just an example for a purpose of demonstration. There is no reason that you have to use only a common `Fragment` class. You can also freely instantiate and replace with different `Fragment` classes.

Comment: ok I see, because what is not clear for me is how can I specify a different layout for each, for instance, on selection one I want to show a list item, on selection 2 i want to show a form and so on,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these links, [one](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and [two](https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android4dev/navigationview/MainActivity.java). The first one is a little bit outdated but it will help you understand the concept of navigation view.

To answer your questions, long story short, you define an area in the layout which will display your fragment layout according to the option you chose. The code in the official Google tutorial demonstrates how to get the selected position and display/replace the fragment.

Hope it helps.

Comment: in the google example i found this
       // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                   .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                   .commit();